# Is their any tab index kind of property in java?

Tags: java, swing

I want to maintain the tab index. [ which we have in .NET ].
But i want this is on my Java application.
So is their properties or method to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by tab index? Do you mean in a GUI of some sort? If so, what GUI library are you using: AWT, Swing, SWT?

Comment: Do you have that in .NET? How does it looks like?

Comment: Can you add a link to a MSDN page indicating what is that dreaded tab index ? By the way, You know that .Net is not a language, but a library ...

Comment: @Gary F...

i was using Swing.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Swing, check out the [Customizing Focus Traversal](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal) section of the Swing tutorial.

Comment: yes...i was using Swing components....thank u....